# Larvel5 Global $config var - fetched form db?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a config table which holds lots of configuration values,
How can I create a static helper/class that will be available globally on laravel?

for example, I have a view with the an input:

`<input type="text" value="<?= SettingsHelper::getValue('my-settings-key'); ?>" />`

And off course i don't want to query each time for it, just one query that gets all the configuration values.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the eloquent ORM and create a model then you can always create objects of that model class anytime you want to call it

Comment: I have a `Setting` model but that is for one setting offcourse, I have like 40-50 settings ,so I'm looking for a place/method to do `Settings::all()` and store that in a helper which is globally available (for controllers, views etc)

Comment: Can't you store all the settings in one table which you called the config table?

Comment: Not sure I get you, but I did store all the settings in one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make like this,

```
class SettingHelper {

    protected $items;

    public function get($key, $default = null)
    {
        if ( empty($this->items))
        {
            $this->loadSettingData();
        }

        if ( array_key_exists($key, $this->items) )
        {
            return $this->items[$key];
        }

        return value($default);
    }

    protected function loadSettingData()
    {
        $this->items = Setting::all()->lists('key', 'value');
    }

}
```

**Need to bind this class in Container with singleton.**

Comment: That's my current helper, the thing is: where do I place it in order to be globally available in laravel and used just like a facade with `SettingsHelper::get('key')`, hope I'm not missing something in the flow.

Comment: First you need to make ServiceProvider class and add config/app.php providers.
Second make Facade for setting and add config/app.php aliases
This is example on pastebin
http://pastebin.com/NyGFT6ri